# How I add two foreign keys?

Tags: mysql

how do I add a second foreign key that it would interact with two tables?
For example:

```
CREATE TABLE Transactions(
    TsID INT NOT NULL,
    BookingDate TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    DepartureDate TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    Passenger INT NOT NULL,
    Flight INT NOT NULL,
    TYPE BLOB NOT NULL,
    Employee INT NOT NULL,
    Charges INT NOT NULL,
    Discount INT NOT NULL,
    fk_ChargesChID INT NOT NULL,
    fk_DiscountsDsID INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pks PRIMARY KEY(TsID),
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY(fk_ChargesChID) REFERENCES Charges(ChID)
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY(fk_EmployeeEmpID) REFERENCES Employee(EmpID)
);
```

how do I make the second foreign key work and not give me this error?:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY(fk_EmployeeEmpID) REFERENCES
>   Employee(EmpID

Charges:
`CREATE TABLE Charges(
    ChID INT NOT NULL,
    Title VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Amount INT(255) NOT NULL,
    Description VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pks PRIMARY KEY(ChID)
);`

Employee:

`CREATE TABLE Employee(
    EmpID INT NOT NULL,
    NAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    Adress VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    Branch INT(100) NOT NULL,
    Designation VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    Email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Tel VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    fk_BranchesBrID INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(EmpID),
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY(fk_BranchesBrID) REFERENCES Branches(BrID)
);`

Comment: Missing a coma after `Charges(ChID)` ?

Answer (score 1):

You only forget the , at
`CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY(fk_ChargesChID) REFERENCES Charges(ChID)` 

if it dont solve your problem, i need to see the other tables

Comment: If I leave both, it still doesn't work, but if I leave either one of the lines it works. what could be the problem?

Comment: You only need one , because last sentence never needs ,

Comment: Finally I recommend you to use an alter table to set all te foreign keys when you have all tables created, You will save yourself problems

Comment: I did add the `,` after where You adviced, now giving me another error

Comment: `#1005 - Can't create table databasemodule.transactions (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")`

Comment: i need to see other tables, I recommend you edit the question and show us the Charges and Employee tables

Comment: I added it, can you check it?

Answer (score 0):

you dont have created fk_EmployeeEmpID at transacctions table.

```
CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY(fk_EmployeeEmpID) REFERENCES Employee(EmpID)
```

i think you want to do this:

```
CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY(Employee) REFERENCES Employee(EmpID)
```

Comment: Tried adding as You suggested and tried creating `fk_EmployeeEmpID`, still not  luck

Comment: Error: `#1005 - Can't create table databasemodule.transactions (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")` and I wrote transaction's table lines like this: `CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY(Charges) REFERENCES Charges(ChID),
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY(Employee) REFERENCES Employee(EmpID)`